# How to reliably know what object is current (in focus) outlook window. i.e. an explorer type or Inspector type

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin, addin-express

We are using an add-in express region, which loads on the right-hand side of Outlook. In that form region, we have one user control, `MyContainer`. This in turn contains two controls.

In `MyContainer`, we need to decide on the visibility of each child control.

A method involving `ActiveInspector` and `ActiveExplorer`, is not reliable.

Example

Opening more than one compose window in the main explorer window, I happen to switch between explorer views, which are; Sent, Outbox, etc. I still find the explorer and inspector objects.

I need a good way to ensure that the window in which my region or MyContainer control is loading in is a compose/read or main Explorer (Inbox/Sent/Drafts/Outbox).

I have tried a number of things, but with no success.

Any pointers or suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Try `Application.ActiveWindow` (which can be either `Explorer` or `Inspector`).

Answer (score 3):

A simple if/else condition can do the job.

The main problem is when the In-line response from Outlook is being used.

That is available since version 13. So we use an empty try/catch to handle that.

```
            Outlook.MailItem Email = null;
            Outlook.Inspector actInspector = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector();
            if (actInspector == null)
            {
                Outlook.Explorer explorer = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer();

                try
                {
                    Email = explorer.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveInlineResponse", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public, null, explorer, null) as Outlook.MailItem;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(explorer);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Email = actInspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (actInspector != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(actInspector);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code can be useful:

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null; 
var windowType = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow(); 
if (windowType is Outlook.Explorer) 
{    
    // Main Explorer
    Outlook.Explorer explorer = windowType as Outlook.Explorer;    
    mailItem = explorer.Selection[0] as Outlook.MailItem; 
}
else if (windowType is Outlook.Inspector) 
{   
    // Read or Compose
    Outlook.Inspector inspector = windowType as Outlook.Inspector;  
    mailItem = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem; 
}
```